# How to create a own CA bundle for import in FireFox using Ansible

Tags: certificate, openssl, tls, ansible

I am trying to create certificates for my own CA. After importing the CA certificate [ca-mydomain.com.crt](https://github.com/onknows/ca/blob/master/ca-mydomain.com.crt) into FireFox my website doesn't work but displays message

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to myapp.mydomain.com Certificate type not approved for application.
>
> Error code: SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE

I followed the following steps:

1. Create for my CA key, csr and crt [ca-mydomain.com.key](https://github.com/onknows/ca/blob/master/ca-mydomain.com.key) [ca-mydomain.com.csr](https://github.com/onknows/ca/blob/master/ca-mydomain.com.csr) and [ca-mydomain.com.crt](https://github.com/onknows/ca/blob/master/ca-mydomain.com.crt)
2. Then for my website I create [myapp.mydomain.com.key](https://github.com/onknows/ca/blob/master/myapp.mydomain.com.key) [myapp.mydomain.com.csr](https://github.com/onknows/ca/blob/master/myapp.mydomain.com.csr) [myapp.mydomain.com.crt](https://github.com/onknows/ca/blob/master/myapp.mydomain.com.crt)

I create these files in two steps using Ansible. For my CA:

```yaml
- community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
    path: ca-mydomain.com.key

- community.crypto.openssl_csr:
    path: ca-mydomain.com.csr
    privatekey_path: ca-mydomain.com.key
    basic_constraints_critical: true
    basic_constraints:
      - CA:TRUE
      - pathlen:0
    key_usage:
      - digitalSignature
      - cRLSign
      - keyCertSign
    common_name: mydomain.com

- openssl_certificate:
    path: ca-mydomain.com.crt
    csr_path: ca-mydomain.com.csr
    privatekey_path: ca-mydomain.com.key
    provider: selfsigned
```

Then for my website:

```yaml
- community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
    path: myapp.mydomain.com.key

- community.crypto.openssl_csr:
    path: myapp.mydomain.com.csr
    privatekey_path: myapp.mydomain.com.key
    key_usage:
      - digitalSignature
      - keyAgreement
    extended_key_usage:
      - clientAuth
    common_name: myapp.mydomain.com

- community.crypto.x509_certificate:
    path: myapp.mydomain.com.crt
    privatekey_path: myapp.mydomain.com.key
    csr_path: myapp.mydomain.com.csr
    ownca_path: ca-mydomain.com.crt
    ownca_privatekey_path: ca-mydomain.com.key
    provider: "{{ ternary('ownca','selfsigned') }}"
```

All certificates I created are in https://github.com/onknows/ca. What is the correct way to create a CA certificate or bundle for import in FireFox, Java keystores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates used by TLS servers must have the `serverAuth` Extended Key Usage.

---

(CAs do not need any Extended Key Usages – the extension can be absent. However, if the CA certificate *does* have EKU, then it should *also* include 'serverAuth' and whatever other EKUs that it'll be issuing for. This is because some implementations will interpret EKU on CA certificates as a constraint over all child certificates.)

Comment: I fixed it by adding `serverAuth` to both ca-mydomain.com.csr and myapp.mydomain.com.csr